# How to mock a socket object via the mock library

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How to mock a `TCPSocket` wrapper for the `socket` from the Python's standard libary via the [mock](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock) library (`unittest.mock` in case of Python 3)?

This is my wrapper:

```
import socket

import utils


class TCPSocket:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buf = ''

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.close()

    def connect(self, host, port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((host, port))

    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()

    def send(self, data):
        self.sock.send(data)

    def sendall(self, data):
        self.sock.sendall(data)

    # For best match with hardware and network realities,
    # the value of limit should be a relatively small power of 2, for example, 4096
    def recv_some(self, limit=4096):
        return self.sock.recv(limit)

    def recv_bytes(self, count):
        while len(self.buf) < count:
            self.buf += self.recv_some()
        parts = utils.split_first_n(self.buf, count)
        self.buf = parts[1]
        return parts[0]

    def recv_until(self, delim):
        while delim not in self.buf:
            self.buf += self.recv_some()
        parts = self.buf.split(delim, maxsplit=1)
        self.buf = parts[1]
        return parts[0]
```

I want to test whether functions like recv_until and recv_bytes do what they really need.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be as simple as

```
import mock   # or from unittest import mock


mock_socket = mock.Mock()
mock_socket.recv.return_value = data
```

then use `mock_socket` where you would use the real socket. You can also mock whatever creates the socket to return a mock value like the one configured here, depending on your needs.

---

For your case, you can mock `socket.socket` so that it returns something whose method you can configure. Note that `mock_socket` in this example is a function that returns a `Socket` object, not a `Socket` object itself.

```
with mock.patch('socket.socket') as mock_socket:
    mock_socket.return_value.recv.return_value = some_data
    t = TCPSocket()
    t.connect('example.com', 12345)  # t.sock is a mock object, not a Socket
self.assertEqual(t.recv_bytes(), whatever_you_expect)
t.sock.connect.assert_called_with(('example.com', 12345))
```

Comment: I don't fully understand how to use this mock object then. I have a wrapper for `socket` from the Python's standard library called `TCPSocket` with methods `connect` and `recv_some`. What should I do then?

Comment: Do you actually need to mock `socket`, or do you need to mock the `TCPSocket` instance? Please edit your question with the exact scenario you need: code that would use the mock object, input, and expected output.

Comment: http://pastie.org/10814947 I want to test whether functions like `recv_until` and `recv_bytes` do what they really need

Comment: In this case it will complain because of the non-initialized `self.sock` instance. So it seems that I need to call the `connect` function that should be patched somehow too

Comment: How does the `connect` function work in this case? It doesn't complain about invalid address even if I don't have a listener on the specified (IP_ADDR, PORT)

Comment: I forgot to actually call `t.connect()`, but fixed that now. Mock objects automatically create new mocks for any attribute you try to access. Since `self.sock` is a `Mock` object, `self.sock.connect` is also a `Mock`, and calling a `Mock` object just returns yet *another* `Mock` object.  In this case, you con't care about the return value. You could test, for example, that `self.sock.connect` was called with the correct arguments.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks a lot! btw, is there any way to patch the same class in several test cases w/o code duplication?

Comment: That's usually handled by your test framework (and better asked in another question). In `unittest`, for example, you put code needed for each test in the `setUp` method of the test case.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `unittest` and yes, I know about the `setUp` method. But I'm asking this question because we patch `socket` inside the `with`-statement

Comment: Looking at your code, I noticed that you merely create the `TCPSocket` instance inside the `with`-statement, not the whole stuff -- `connect`, `recv` etc. Am I right that I just need to create an instance that will use the mocked object inside the `with`-statement while other code can be placed outside?

Comment: I think that you should move the `connect` call to the `with`-statement to construct the patched `socket` object there

Comment: So we just have to construct a patched object inside the `with`-statement and then we can use it anywhere. Am I right?

Comment: Right. `socket.socket` is only patched inside the body of the `with` statement, but once we call `TCPSocket.connect`, the value of `self.sock` persists.

Comment: How would one use that mock up when a method in a class does for example:  sock.connect_ex(self.server_address)