# Mocked method socket.accept() is not called

Tags: python, sockets, mocking, server-side

I am trying to mock server side of socket. This example is not working and I don't know why (it still uses original socket.socket.accept() method).
Any ideas how to mock listening socket correctly?

```
class MySocket:
    def __init__:
        self.socket = socket.socket()
    def listen(self):
        self.socket.accept()  # original socket method

class MockConn:
    def recv(self, int):
        return b'' 
    def close(self):
        pass
    def sendall(self, str):
        pass

with mock.patch('socket.socket') as mock_socket:
    conn = MockConn()
    mock_socket.return_value.accept.return_value = (conn, 'localhost')
    s = MySocket(None)
    s.listen()  # this should call accept from the mock
```

Comment: Apply the patch where it is imported to, not where it is imported from.

Comment: It seems that you have taken your mocking code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36889066 , but the question there uses sockets like this: `self.socket = socket.socket(...) self.socket.accept()`

Comment: @quamrana Yes, I was inspired by this thread, but note that it's a client side, I am trying to write a server side. If it was working I wouldn't duplicate the question. :-)

Comment: You still need to create a `socket` object.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't understand how you mean that. :-/ Where should I exactly import the mock.patch?

Comment: I see you have edited the question. The line `self.socket = socket.socket()` is not valid. Did you mean to add this to the `__init__()` function?

Comment: @quamrana You are right, I've fixed it.

Comment: Does that mean your code, as now posted, works?

Comment: @quamrana No, it still uses socket.socket().accept() instead of mocked version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but this works:

```
import socket
from unittest import mock

class MySocket:
    def listen(self):
        print('Accept result:', socket.socket().accept())  
        # Accept result: (<__main__.MockConn object at 0x000001E592B36B38>, 'localhost')

class MockConn:
    def recv(self, int):
        return b'' 
    def close(self):
        pass
    def sendall(self, str):
        pass

with mock.patch('socket.socket') as mock_socket:
    conn = MockConn()
    mock_socket.return_value.accept.return_value = (conn, 'localhost')
    s = MySocket()
    s.listen()
```

Answer (score 0):

With some very minor changes to your current code this works:

```
from unittest import mock
import socket

class MySocket:
    def __init__(self):    # init takes self
        self.socket = socket.socket()
    def listen(self):
        return self.socket.accept()  # original socket method

class MockConn:
    def recv(self, int):
        return b''
    def close(self):
        pass
    def sendall(self, str):
        pass

with mock.patch('socket.socket') as mock_socket:
    conn = MockConn()
    mock_socket.return_value.accept.return_value = (conn, 'localhost')
    s = MySocket()
    print(s.listen())  # this should call accept from the mock
```

Output:

```
(<__main__.MockConn object at 0x00000255C5A53B00>, 'localhost')
```